# Issue with Saga locking when using optimistic concurrency mode and message retry

Tags: masstransit

I am using MassTransit.SAGA with CurrencyMode = 'ConcurrencyMode.Optimistic' and using messageRetry to handle with fault message (I set the interval time with 100ms). So I expect that fault message should be re-scheduled later after 100ms delay but I got MassTransitException state that 'Unable to lock saga' with "Retrying {Delay}: {Message}" around 1 sec.

{"@t":"**2023-07-10T08:40:30.9897261Z**","@mt":"Retrying {Delay}: {Message}","@l":"Warning","@x":"MassTransit.MassTransitException: Unable to lock saga: States.OrderDetailState(cb2f012d-3cb8-4a5d-808e-0a726a095d59_lock)\n   at MassTransit.RedisIntegration.Contexts.RedisDatabaseContext`1.SagaLock.<Lock>g__LockAsync|6_0()\n   at MassTransit.Policies.PipeRetryExtensions.Retry[T](IRetryPolicy retryPolicy, Func`1 retryMethod, CancellationToken cancellationToken)","**Delay":"00:00:01.1990000"**,"Message":"Unable to lock saga: States.OrderDetailState(cb2f012d-3cb8-4a5d-808e-0a726a095d59_lock)","SourceContext":"MassTransit.ReceiveTransport"}

and after 1 sec pass , we get R-RETRY message

{"@t":**"2023-07-10T08:40:32.2093178Z"**,"@mt":"R-RETRY {InputAddress} {MessageId} {MessageType}","@l":"Warning","@x":"MassTransit.SagaException: States.OrderDetailState(cb2f012d-3cb8-4a5d-808e-0a726a095d59) Saga exception: Saga update failed\n ---> MassTransit.RedisIntegration.RedisSagaConcurrencyException: States.OrderDetailState(cb2f012d-3cb8-4a5d-808e-0a726a095d59) Saga exception: Saga version conflict\n

Noted: I run this SAGA process with 3 pods.

**Question**
I have no idea why I got retrying delayed message when I set up the concurrency mode with 'Optimistic'

Here is my MassTransit set up in coding

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: No clue, you'd need to pursue this with a complete standalone repository and create a GitHub discussion if you're expecting free support. Otherwise, you can contact [commercial support](https://masstransit.io/support) if you're a customer (or to become one).

Comment: I wonder if I set the concurrencymode = optimistic. I shouldn't get any  redis lock issue , right ?

Comment: IAsyncDisposable updateLock = **_options.ConcurrencyMode == ConcurrencyMode.Optimistic**
                ? updateLock = await Lock(instance, context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)
                : null;

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to configure it in saga state machine itself like this:

```cs
config.AddSagaStateMachine<TStateMachine,TState>(s =>
        {
            s.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(settings.MessageRetryAttempts, settings.MessageRetryInterval));
        })
        .RedisRepository(...)
```